# How can I test if the mouse draw on the active tiles?

Tags: libgdx

I want to draw some sprites in a tiledmap where the tiles are active.
I want to draw with the mouse, so how could I compare the position of the mouse, the sprite position and the position of active tiles?
I tried to compare:
`sprite.getX`, `screenX` and `cell.getTile (). getProperties (). containsKey ("active")` 
but I can not get the position of the active tiles.

Answer (score 1):

The libgdx camera type [OrthographicCamera](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html) has an [unproject method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-). Supplying this method with the screen coordinates of the mouse click will give you a position in world space you can then use collision detection with on your tiles.

The following code shows how you might get the mouse coodinate and traslate it into a world space point.

```
Vector3 clickPos = new Vector3();
clickPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
camera.unproject(clickPos);
```

At the end of this code snippet you can expect clickPos to now relate to a position in world space.

As noted by the API documentation, setting the z value of the input vector will give you a position at a distance along the ray spanning from the near to far plane. In the example, the z value is 0 therefore the returned coordinate will be on the camera's near plane. However, assuming this is orthographic this should be fine.

Getting the cell could then be done using [getCell](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TiledMapTileLayer.html#getCell-int-int-);

```
TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = TiledMapTileLayer.getCell(clickPos.x, clickPos.y);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it will not allow me to define the position of the tiles I want, for the coordinates of the mouse I used MouseMouve and mouseDragged.